# If the Camel Route crashes, is it removed from the Camel Context? If not, how can I check that it is no longer executed?

Tags: java, apache-camel, readinessprobe

I have a readiness probe based on the fact that the number of Apache Camel routes loaded to the `CamelContext` isn't decreasing. Am I right and can rely on this count as a scent of silently failed routes?

```
    logger.info("Routes in context count:" + camelContext.getRoutes().size());
    logger.info("Routes in context:" + camelContext.getRoutes().stream().map(Route::getId).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
  
    Integer camelContextRoutesCountLocal = camelContext.getRoutes().size();
    if (camelContextRoutesCountLocal != camelContextRoutesCount.get()) {
        logger.info("Previous routes count: "+camelContextRoutesCount.get());
        logger.info("New routes count: "+camelContextRoutesCountLocal);
        if (camelContextRoutesCountLocal < camelContextRoutesCount.get()) {
            decreaseFlag = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        }
        camelContextRoutesCount = new AtomicInteger(camelContextRoutesCountLocal);
        logger.error("New routes count isn't the same as was before");
        //throw new Exception();
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
    }
    if (decreaseFlag.get()) {
        logger.error("The number of loaded routes once was decreased");
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
        //throw new Exception();
    }
```

Is there some other way to make a readinessprobe to fail if some loaded route has been crashed and no longer serves the application?